# JSON data to time

Tags: javascript, json, string, time

I had some data in JSON format. There is stored time as a string(like: "3-45 AM"). Now I want to add 20 minutes to this. How can I do this?

I tried something like this,

```
let initial = '3-45 AM';
const replaceText = ''+(Number(initial.slice(2, 4))+2);

const last2Charecter = initial.slice(-5, -3);

const final = initial.replace(last2Charecter, replaceText)

console.log(final)
```

But problem is, when mm become 60+ it couldn't work.

Comment: If you dont want to suffer, use something parsable, e.g. `Date.prototype.toISOString`, when serializing. You can do your own special thing, but the root issue is really this custom format (requiring custom everything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you continue to use this custom format, you should be able to first split the string by spaces, so you get `3-45` and `AM`, then you can split the `3-45` string by `-` to get `3` and `45`, hour and minute, and work with them.

```js
let time = "3-45 AM";
const addendum = 30;

let [ numbers, meridiem ] = time.split(' ');
let [ hour, minute ] = numbers.split('-').map(Number);

minute += addendum;

while(minute >= 60) {
  minute -= 60;
  
  hour++;
}
  
if(hour > 12) {
  meridiem = (meridiem == "AM")?("PM"):("AM");
  
  hour -= 12;
}
  
console.log(hour + "-" + minute + " " + meridiem);
```